# Display glitches with multiple monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, google-chrome, display-rotation

Whenever i open Chrome or a Chromium based app (discord for example) it causes my screen to flicker black and then when the displays come back on my display settings have been reverted to an old state.

I've recently switched my portrait monitor back to landscape so you can see how this is problematic

Another weird glitch is when changing the display settings my screen flickers black as normal and shows the "keep changes or revert" modal however the changes displayed are the original old settings and not the new ones. In order for my displays to persist the new settings i need to click "Revert settings"... Let me know if you need any more information as i understand this is a visual issue and not the easiest to describe.